# New column content not appearing in search results (with use of managed property filter)

Tags: column, managed-metadata, managed-property, crawled-property, advanced-search

I followed the instructions [here](https://waelmohamed.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/add-custom-search-properties-in-your-advanced-search-sharepoint-2010/) to add a new property in advanced search, and to be able to search based on the custom column I made (which are metadata tags).

It worked well last week; but this week I started editing existing documents within the same library to add their metadata tags. When searching, however, the content with new tags don't appear - just the old ones which appeared last time. This is even when I added the same tags to other files in the library. For instance, file A with metadata tag (in the custom column) 'Documents' appear in the search results, but file B with the exact same tag, but added only now, does not appear.

I have tried full crawling 3 times, as well as re-mapping the managed property to the crawled property.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve found the problem! It turns out that the new files I added were automatically added as ‘checked out’. I just had to check them in and now they’re fully searchable! I only discovered the problem because I checked the same list through a colleague’s account (who also has full permission) and noticed that the files don’t appear in his account. I then started checking the properties and noticed the ‘Check In’ button.

It’s funny I didn’t notice that before, and I feel kinda dumb! hehe. Well now to check why they were uploaded as checked out, and prevent that from happening.

UPDATE: I realised that the reason my newly uploaded files were checked out is because I uploaded them using multiple uploads, while I have some properties which are required to be filled in for every file. To comply, SP checked them out by default. I couldn't check them in without adding the appropriate property content first. So I added the properties, then checked them in.